# Getting variable values from key value dataframe

Tags: r

Starting with the following dataframe

```
key = c("A", "B", "C") 
value = c(1, 2, 3) 
df = data.frame(key,value)
```

How can I design a function to apply a formula based on the key

for example, A+B*C should return 1+2*3 = 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could convert it to a `list` and then apply the logic

```
lst <- split(df$value, df$key)
lst[['A']] + lst[['B']] * lst[['C']]
#[1] 7
```

---

Or convert the `list` to three column dataset and using `with`, get the output

```
with(as.data.frame(lst), A + B * C)
#[1] 7
```

Or this can also work as the `list` elements are of `length` 1

```
with(lst, A + B * C)
#[1] 7
```